# Loading data from CSV file in Sharepoint to SQL Server table

Tags: ssis, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to load data from "CSV file in Sharepoint online" to "Sql Server table" using SSIS without downloading the file to local folders. (I need to deploy the package to Integration Service Catalogs in Sql Server)

Could anyone help me on solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Odata Source with a OData Connection to Access Sharepoint Lists with files. There are a couple tutorials:

- https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-configure-odata-ssis-connection-for-sharepoint-online/
- https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2021/01/08/connecting-to-sharepoint-lists-with-ssis/